# AgentScope activity in custom activity of TFS 2013

Tags: tfsbuild

I try to encapsulate build process and make custom activities reusable as much as possible and created my own custom activity that has AgentScope activity in it. Inside AgentScope I added two standard activities: GetEnvironmentVariable and WriteBuildMessage that should display BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Id. In this case build throws 2 exceptions:

Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail1.BuildDefinition.Id".
Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined.
And 
Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BuildDetail".
'Activities' is not a member of 'Build'.
(the exception is thrown only if I try to extract members of IBuildDetail)

If I add the same AgentScope directly to Build Template then the build passes without exceptions.

I use VB expressions in my template and custom activity. Build Controller and Build Agent both run on the same computer with Windows 2008 R2 server. VS 2010, 2013 and 2015 of highest editions are installed. I use TFS 2013 build server.

So the question consists of several parts:

1. Is there any limitation on where to put AgentScope activity?
2. Are there special configurations for Build Agent or Build controller?
3. And is it possible at all to add AgentScope to any custom activity rather then to BuildTemplate?

Thank you.

Comment: AgentScope activity is used to enclose the parts of your build process that you want to run on the build agent. Could you specify the custom activity? What is this for?

Comment: We want to create activities for creating the installations based on different installation technologies (WIX, InstallShield 2008, InstallShield 2010, etc.). We want that every process will run on different agent with different tools installed on it. Also we want that every activity will be self contained and includes AgentScope activity. Thus we see the ability to include our activities in different Build Templates without customizing them much.